# ValueError: time data '' does not match format '%Y%m%S'

Tags: python, string, datetime

I know this something stupid, bus i have this problem with converting string to datetime in python:

```
dateStr = currentFileName[pos:pos+8];
datetime_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(dateStr, '%Y%m%S');
```

I get:

> ValueError: time data '' does not match format '%Y%m%d'

However when i assign the variable directly

```
dateStr = "20181011";
datetime_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(dateStr, '%Y%m%S');
```

It works perfect. Any thoughts will be helpful. Thanks

Comment: The format string in your error is different from your code.

Comment: Hi Cesar !! Welcome to Stack Overflow!! I think you should first make sure the string given by ```dateStr = currentFileName[pos:pos+8]``` is a datetime string, may be there might be some problem with the value of variable : pos

Comment: http://strftime.org/  (`"%S - Second as a zero-padded decimal number."`)

Comment: What's are the value and type of `dateStr` before you attempt applying `strptime()`?

Comment: i already solved it. The problem was my program stored an invalid string od datetime in an iteration. Sorry and Thanks!!